# How can I inject two implementations as once with Unity?

Tags: c#, interface, unity-container

I have a `IConsole` interface, describing how to write stuff to the console, and one implementation, `upperCaseConsole`.

IConsole is injected in the `Foo` class using Unity.

```
public interface IConsole {
 void WriteLine(string text);   
}

public class upperCaseConsole: IConsole {
    public void WriteLine(string text){
    Console.WriteLine(text.ToUpper());  
    }
}

public class Foo{
 private readonly IConsole console;
    public Foo(IConsole console){
    this.console = console; 
    }

    public void WriteStuff(string stuff){
    console.WriteLine(stuff);
    }
}
```

I would now like to change how the text is written to the console. I have done a good job decoupling the implementation from foo, and I can just inject a new implementation, say `lowerCaseConsole` instead.

```
public class lowerCaseConsole: IConsole {
    public void WriteLine(string text){
    Console.WriteLine(text.ToLower());  
    }
}
```

My problem is, despite my best tests, I am not really sure that `lowerCaseConsole` will do the job, and I would like to run both implementations simultaneously for a while.

How can I do it without duplicating all the code in `Foo`?

I would like to avoid something like:

```
public class Foo{
     private readonly IConsole lowerConsole;
     private readonly IConsole upperConsole;

        public Foo([Dependency("lower")] IConsole lowerConsole,
             [Dependency("upper")] IConsole upperConsole){
        this.lowerConsole = lowerConsole;
        this.upperConsole = upperConsole;   
        }

        public void WriteStuff(string stuff){
        lowerConsole.WriteLine(stuff);
        upperConsole.WriteLine(stuff);
        }
    }
```

Note: The real-life case is that I am about to move forward on a DB change. I would like to transparently start writing to the new DB, and see how things go, but keep writing to the current DB, just in case.

Comment: Make another class that implements `IConsole` and have both the upper and lower implementations injected to it and it just forwards the calls to them.  Then inject that into Foo.

Comment: Alternatively you can drop injection and instead do this with events.  Then you can subscribe as many implementations as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create a third implementation that contains private members of the other two, and calls to it's `WriteLine` method would just be forwarded to both the other types.

```
public class BothCaseConsole : IConsole
{
    private readonly LowerCaseConsole lcc = new LowerCaseConsole();
    private readonly UpperCaseConsole ucc = new UpperCaseConsole();

    public void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        lcc.WriteLine(text);
        ucc.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Then just inject this type into `Foo`:

```
new Foo(new BothCaseConsole()).WriteStuff("Stuff to write");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use named registration to inject `IEnumerable<IConsole>`. This approach is easily extendable with more implementations...or you could easily remove one of them...

```
container.RegisterType<IConsole, LowerConsole>("LowerConsole");
container.RegisterType<IConsole, UpperConsole>("UpperConsole");
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IConsole>, IConsole[]>();
```

then the ctor of the `Foo` becomes a bit different and also the `WriteStuff` method...

```
public Foo(IEnumerable<IConsole> consoles)
{
    this.consoles = consoles; 
}

public void WriteStuff(string stuff)
{
    foreach(var console in consoles)
    {
        console.WriteLine(stuff);
    }
}
```